# position elements relative to parent

Tags: css, svg, position

I am trying to make a resizable window within SVG, in which I want to have little indicators where the window can be dragged to resize it. I've currently got the following:

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
<rect x="25" y="25" width="150" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="5,5" />
<g fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
    <rect x="23" y="23" width="5" height="5" style="cursor:nw-resize" />
    <rect x="173" y="23" width="5" height="5" style="cursor:ne-resize" />
    <rect x="173" y="123" width="5" height="5" style="cursor:se-resize" />
    <rect x="23" y="123" width="5" height="5" style="cursor:sw-resize" />
</g>
</svg>
```

but if I want to resize that, I'd have to update three of the `<rect>`s whenever one of the corners is being resized, or if I would add squares in the middle of the line (like what MS Paint uses), I'd have to update 5 at a time.

So is it possible to position these four boxes relative to a parent `<g>`? That way I would only have to resize the one `<g>`'s `width` and `height` to automatically move all of the `<rect>`s. It seems to me this kind of thing (grouping SVG elements together) is what the `<g>` tag was invented for, but I couldn't find anything on how to do what I want to do here.

Comment: resize by setting and adjusting a viewBox on th svg element and then you won't need to change the position of any of the content elements.

Comment: @RobertLongson well, it's only a part of the svg. It's supposed to be a selection window so you can resize what's below it. So, resizing the viewbox isn't really a possibility (or am I missing something?)

Comment: `<svg>` elements nest so stick what you want to resize in an inner `<svg>` element and alter its viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson oh I didn't know that. Could you post that as an answer? I think that's going to be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<svg>` elements nest so stick what you want to resize in an inner `<svg>` element and alter its viewBox

The viewBox defines the area visible within an element so if you make it bigger the contents will appear smaller and vice versa.